# Maximum Pending Requests

Tags: javascript

I have a issue. I call 6 requests and have a timeout (without VPN) and stay like this for like 20 seconds. 
When I make the 7th request, and this one should work, it stays pending until the others resolve. It seems that the max pendingRequests is 6.

console.log($http.pendingRequests.length); // retuns 6 when I have 7 pending

Is there a way to increase this value?

Comment: Hi, is this question related to Java?

Comment: Maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this cannot be changed programatically. You can find a list of the browsers' default max concurrent requests per domain setting [here](https://www.browserscope.org/?category=network). As a user, you can usually configure this value in the advanced settings section (e.g. `about:config` for [Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server)) of your browser. However, unless you have control of the users' browsers (such as company deployments), that is likely not an option.

As a programmer without access to the browser config you basically have two options:

Either you distribute your http requests to different domains (which resolve to the same server), or you abort some of your first 6 requests using `XMLHttpRequest.abort()` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) - exact usage may vary due to the framework you are using) and requeue them later on.